# Facebook Comment Mirroring doesn't work part of the time

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

EDIT: This has been confirmed as a bug by Facebook. You can follow its' progress here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1624076297911442/

We have set up Facebook Comment mirroring and it isn't mirroring the comments from Facebook to our website all the time. The URLs are posted utilizing the exact same tactics (no extra slash, no www, etc.). The URL that is loaded in the DOM on the page is the same exact URL that is posted on Facebook.

**Here is an example of an article not working:**

FB: https://www.facebook.com/djboothnet/posts/10153619844952006

URL: http://djbooth.net/news/entry/2015-05-23-eminem-childhood-home-bricks

**Here is an example of an article working:**

FB: https://www.facebook.com/djboothnet/posts/10153621575602006

URL: http://djbooth.net/news/entry/2016-05-24-oprah-paul-mccartney-kanye-west-block

These **ARE** new web pages that were created after we enabled the setting. Look at the posted date on the entries. There are entries older than that Eminem one that have comment mirroring working.

Example:

http://djbooth.net/news/entry/2016-05-23-biggie-grape-juice-big-poppa-lyrics
https://www.facebook.com/djboothnet/posts/10153619528772006

Answer (score 0):

Comment mirroring only works for new URLs, that you added the comments plugin to for the first time after comment mirroring was enabled.

There is no way to activate it for older URLs, that have already been commented on before.

Comment: These ARE new web pages that were created after we enabled the setting. Look at the posted date on the entries. There are entries older than that Eminem one that have comment mirroring working.

Example:
http://djbooth.net/news/entry/2016-05-23-biggie-grape-juice-big-poppa-lyrics
https://www.facebook.com/djboothnet/posts/10153619528772006

Comment: According to the date in the URL, your Eminem article is over a year old. And comment mirroring did not even exist back then IIRC.

Comment: Url is incorrect. Look in the actual article. It says Posted 19 hours ago. There are a bunch of other articles that don't work and a bunch that do.

Answer (score 0):

I have also noticed that not all posts has a comments mirroring. You can ensure and get more information from the Facebook API about if posts has `comments_mirroring_domain` filled with proper domain.

Please follow the checklist: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40578720/1815881

Notice, that From 6th Feb 2018 Facebook comments mirroring is deprecated and no longer supported.

> Comment Mirroring: Pages that currently have Comment Mirroring enabled
>   will continue to mirror comments for the next 90 days. Full
>   deprecation of Comment Mirroring will conclude on 2/6/2018. Comment
>   Mirroring is no longer available for Pages that do not have it enabled
>   already.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/