# Facebook Comments Mirroring doesn't work

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-comments, facebook-app-settings

Step by step i did these

1. Create a new Facebook App (App ID: 544557495732050)
2. Create a new Facebook Page (https://www.facebook.com/Pasha-electronic-502844156580479/)
3. In App which created by step 1 check yes  (Yes, mirror to page - which created on step 2) https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments
4. Create a new web page (which include javascript src and div tag) http://pasha-k.az/ramin/test.html
5. Share this link on Facebook Page which created by step 2 https://www.facebook.com/Pasha-electronic-502844156580479/)

**Problem:** I see different comments. Comment mirroring does not work.

Comment: I have same problem with this issue. Did you resolved this already?

Comment: unfortunately no :(

Comment: Maybe this could help. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1624076297911442/ Update me when you found something new. Thank you!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1624076297911442/ helped me

Answer (score 4):

**Checklist**:

1. Your FB app status is "This app is public and available to all users" https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
2. Your FB page status is "Page is visible to everyone" in page's Settings > Country Restrictions
3. Your FB page status is "Page is shown to everyone" in page's Settings > Age Restrictions
4. Your URL points to the right page on your website
5. Your webpage has this META tag:

   ```
   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR_APP_ID" />
   ```
6. The META tag above has attribute property= instead of standard name=
7. There are no curly braces {} around your APP ID in the META tag.
8. You enabled mirroring and selected your page in Moderation Tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/
9. There is no extra extra slash / in your url
10. You posted the exact URL in your FB page, as the page administrator
11. On top of your post you see an Earth icon; move your mouse over and you see "Public"
12. When you comment on your webpage, you see this note under the comment area: "Your comment may also appear on XYZ's Facebook Page."
13. When you comment your FB post, you see this note under the comment area: "This comment will also be posted to www.sample.com."
14. You can fix errors using the FB Sharing Debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
15. You can clear FB sharing cache associated with your url https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/batch/

**Workarounds**:

1. Append # at the end of your URL
2. Try your URL without www

**Bug Report**:

You can submit a bug report to Facebook for Developer page https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

**Notes**:

Comment mirroring takes effect on new webpages created after the setting has been enabled. The first you time share the URL, current mirroring status is retained for that URL - forever.

Comment: Why does appending "#" fix this problem?

Comment: Hello, Charlies. Appending # does not solve the problem. If for any reason FB doesn't want to activate comments mirroring, the URL with # is treated as a new URL and you can start from scratch to setup comments mirroring. Obscur reasons could be: the first URL was added to FB database before comments mirroring was developed, the URL is internally marked as blocked or invalid, etc.

Comment: We've recently got an SSL so our sites are now https. One of the issues has been the effect on comments. I changed the url to not include "http://" and comments now work for SOME pages only. Why might they not work for others (may not be https issues)?

Answer (score 4):

From 6th Feb 2018 Facebook comments mirroring is deprecated and no longer supported.

> Comment Mirroring: Pages that currently have Comment Mirroring enabled
>   will continue to mirror comments for the next 90 days. Full
>   deprecation of Comment Mirroring will conclude on 2/6/2018. Comment
>   Mirroring is no longer available for Pages that do not have it enabled
>   already.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/

Comment: Thanks, saved so much of my time debugging the issue